# Do dynamic wallpapers drain battery?

Tags: ios, ipad, battery

Is it true that using a dynamic wallpaper will drain the battery faster than a still wallpaper? If so, how much faster does it drain?

(I'm using an iPad Air running on iOS 7.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, dynamic wallpapers drain the battery faster than still wallpapers. The amount of drainage is dependent on the wallpaper itself (whether it has many bright colors, is graphic intensive) and how it's programmed (CPU and memory usage, etc.). There are ones that are better than others. Also, how often are you on your home screen where you see that wall paper? Obviously it will only affect you battery life if it is on the screen, so if you are using apps all the time you should see virtually no difference. I would suggest experimenting with your iPad's battery life with a dynamic wallpaper and without, and see how they vary with your usage.

Comment: The color brightness of a wallpaper doesn't affect battery life. The power consumption of an LCD screen is constant and is unaffected by the color of the image.

Comment: dcgoss is partly right. On some phones the wallpaper won't wff the battery life but on androids like the Galaxy s3 bright wall papers will drain your batrery faster

Comment: Colorful backgrounds drain more battery life in an OLED screen than darker backgrounds, as black colors actually turn off the pixels that are black. In LCD screens this concept doesn't apply.